# Is the proof making any sense?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I came across this question in MSE to determine if n tend to infinity is $y_n$ converge or diverge.

$y_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}y_n$

wonder can I proof also by using ratio test and contradiction as below?

$\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=\frac{n}{(n+1)y_n}+\frac{2}{3}$

Assume $n$ tend to infinity, $y_n$ tend to infinity

$\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=\frac{2}{3}$ which is a contradiction as ratio smaller than $1$ but diverge? so the sequence cannot be diverge?

and for the case $y_n$ converge to $y_{n+1}$ so ratio is 1(not possible $0$ since have the term $\frac{n}{n+1}$)

$1=\frac{1}{y_n}+\frac{2}{3}$

hence $y_n=3$ when $n$ tend to infinity? But I read somewhere if ratio test=1 cannot conclude anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} > \frac23$ for all $n,$ so you cannot use $\frac23$ in the ratio test.

But if you can show that there is a number $r$ between $\frac23$ and $1$ and an integer $N$ such that $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} < r$ for all $n>N,$
then you can apply the ratio test.

For the other part you're not using the ratio test.
You're simply solving for $y$ in $y = 1 + \frac23 y.$
But I think you need a bit more than that to constitute a proof.
Now that you think you know what the limit it, it gives you a big advantage when you try to prove the limit.

Comment: Thank for explanation